# Rails Strong Parameters - create action with foreign key parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models, Server has many maintenances and Maintenance belongs to Server and User.

```
create_table :maintenances do |t|
  t.references :server, foreign_key: true
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.string :name
  t.text :content
end
```

In console I can create records as follows:

```
Server.create(:hostname => "Sissy", :description => "Webserver")
Maintenance.create(:server_id => 1, :user_id => 1, :name => "Test", :content => "Test" )
```

My Question is: How can I do this in my Controller create action?
Problem is that `:user_id` is not part of the maintenance params hash, so if I write

```
def create
  @server = Server.find(params[:id])
  @maintenance = @server.maintenances.create!(maintenance_params)
end

  private
    def maintenance_params
      params.require(:maintenance).permit(:user_id => current_user.id, 
                                          :id, 
                                          :name, 
                                          :content)    
    end
```

I'm getting

```
Syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...ser_id => current_user.id, :id, :name, :content, :start, :pl...
...                               ^):

app/controllers/maintenances_controller.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
```

Comment: The syntax error is because you cannot have a hash key before the ordinal arguments in a method call in ruby. `permit(:id, :name, :content, :user_id => current_user.id)` is syntactically valid - but you should use a block instead to assign values from the session instead of merging them into the incoming parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't do anything like that in strong_params method. Nor is it its purpose. Separate the whitelisting and default params.

I usually do it like this:

```
def create
  @server      = Server.find(params[:id])
  @maintenance = @server.maintenances.create!(maintenance_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
end

private
def maintenance_params
  params.require(:maintenance).permit(:id, :name, :content)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add , user_id inside your create action itself. Try this.

```
def create
  @server = Server.find(params[:id])
  params[:maintenance][:user_id] = current_user.id
  @maintenance = @server.maintenances.create!(maintenance_params)
end
```

Comment: record is getting saved but user_id is empty. (i don't have nested parameters or something like that written in my model)

Answer (score 2):

A good way is by passing a block to the `create!` method:

```
@maintenance = @server.maintenances.create!(maintenance_params) do |m|
  m.user = current_user
end
```

The record is yielded to the block (before it is validated/saved).

This also works with `new`, `create`, `update` and `update!`.

But you should consider if you should be using the bang method `create!` here as it will raise an uncaught `ActiveRecord::RecordNotValid` error if any of the validations fail.

```
def create
  @server = Server.find(params[:id])
  @maintenance = @server.maintenances.new(maintenance_params) do |m|
    m.user = current_user
  end
  if @maintenance.save
    redirect_to @maintenance
  else
    render :new 
  end
end
```

The ActiveRecord::Persistence bang methods should only really be used in things like seed files or where a record not passing the validations is an exceptional event.